# What do I put in "type" when I fill the MySQL table with a slideshow (made in Adobe Edge Animate) archive?

Tags: mysql, database, jquery-animate, adobe-edge

I'm building a dynamic database and I want to put a slideshow inside the database. I'm building this database with MySQL, using a SQL connection and I'll build the website with Dreamweaver CC(php)

Answer (score 0):

Use LONGBLOB.This means you can basically put anything in the column.